# Windows shows no domain prefix after simple join to the domain

Tags: windows-10, domain, windows-domain, windows-server-2016

My domain is `nerv.com`. I managed to add second server to the domain. The first image shows what I meant about simple join:

[image: The image 1]

The second image shows the situation in the clear way. As you can see there is no prefix:

[image: The Image 2]

Is there a way to add my domain prefix to look as NERV\Administrator?

Answer (score 1):

This is normal, because the label usually doesn't show the username in the first place – it shows the account's *displayName* when available. The display name is meant to contain the user's real name, so it never has the domain prefix unless you add it by hand.

(Second, the account 'Administrator' gets special treatment in the login screen – if you enter this username into the "Other user" screen without entering the domain prefix, Windows will by default log you into the *local* Admin account instead of the domain one.)

Comment: Yes but on the DC there was a prefix. Then I made separate full admin AD domain account and disabled local admins everywhere. Now there is either no NERV\login prefix and the description _"Login: nerv.com"_

Answer (score 0):

Administrator could be both a remote AND a domain login. I would highly suggest you make a separate login (i.e. `daniel.vazome`) and make that account a domain admin.

Once that is done, if the computer is joined to the domain AND all local accounts are disabled (very important), then you should be able to do

1. Login Screen -> Other User
2. It should say `Login: nerv.com` with a link explaining how to login to a different domain.

The only time I've ever had to use a Domain prefix was when logging into RDC over my work VPN (my home machine is not on the domain so I have to state where to look for authentication)

Comment: Well I made that you said but there is still no NERV\ prefix in the name and description like _"Login: nerv.com"_ maybe I missed something